# Stack Exchange OpenID not working

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, openid, stack-exchange-openid

When trying to log in by clicking the "Login With Stack Exchange" option, the login dialog will not appear.

When trying to [log in to Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/login), it gives me a "504 Gateway Time Out" error:

[image: screenshot]

I am using Chrome 13.0.782.32 beta, Mac OS X 10.6.8. I can reproduce the error on multiple networks and devices.

Comment: https://openid.stackexchange.com/ is not loading when clicking login as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Side effect of network changes this Sunday; apologies. Now fixed.